# Replace all class instances with stub

Tags: php, phpunit

I am testing a class, let's call it `ClassUnderTest` using another class, let's call it `OtherClass`. In my Test I do:

```php
$OtherClassStub = $this->createStub(OtherClass::class);
$OtherClassStub->method(...)
    ->willReturn(...);
$ClassUnderTest->otherClass = $OtherClassStub;
```

That works. But when the `$ClassUnderTest` calls `new OtherClass()`, the original `OtherClass` class is created instead of the stub.

How can I achieve that every possible instance of `OtherClass` in the context of the test is replaced by the stub?

Comment: Are you on vanilla PHP or are you using a framework?

Comment: php-unit 9.5 is my only dependency

Comment: Could you please clarify your code example? You're talking about ClassUnderTest, OtherClass, $sessionController and $SessionDao, but it's not clear to me how they're used together.

Comment: I don't think you can call partial function on another partial like this `$OtherClassStub->method(...)
    ->willReturn(...);` Did you mean to use first-class callable here or did you just mangle up the code when pasting here?

Comment: `$OtherClassStub->method('methodName')->willReturn('value);` works.

Comment: Are you saying that after you replaced the callables with actual method calls with parameter, it works and your problem is solved? If so then I think the question can be deleted as a typo.

Comment: What works is: I create the Stub of `OtherClass`, inject the instance to the `ClassUnderTest` and it is used. The Question is: Can I archive that this Stub will be used everytime `ClassUnderTest` creates a **new OtherClass()**.

Comment: Why would you use plain PHP instead of a framework? My personal recommendation is to use a framework, don't try to reinvent the wheel, Laravel and Symfony already solved a lot of issues, don't try to solve them again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description I infer that in principle you have something like this:

```php
class OtherClass {
    protected function someMethod(): bool
    {
        // determine $x ...
        return $x;
    }
}

class ClassUnderTest {
    public OtherClass $otherClass;

    public function methodToBeTested(): bool
    {
        $otherClass = new OtherClass();
        return $otherClass->someMethod();
    }
}

class ClassUnderTestTest extends TestCase {
    public function testMethodToBeTested(): void
    {
        $otherClassStub = $this->createStub(OtherClass::class);
        $otherClassStub->method('someMethod')
            ->willReturn(true);
        $classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();
        $classUnderTest->otherClass = $otherClassStub;
        
        $result = $classUnderTest->methodToBeTested();
        $this->assertTrue($result);
    }
}
```

Now the assertion in your test may hold or it may fail. Why? Because you are not calling the method you stubbed on the `$otherClassStub`. Instead you instantiate a new `$otherClass` object in the method you're testing (or somewhere down the line).

Either your `ClassUnderTest` should always use the `OtherClass` object from the `ClassUndertTest::otherClass` attribute (assuming that's why you put it there in the first place).

Or you could use some other form of dependency injection, e.g. by using a framework like Symfony or Laravel. (In the case of Symfony you can even use *only* the [DependencyInjection Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html), no idea if that's possible with Laravel, too.)

The simple answer to your actual question is: you cannot change the behaviour of the `new` keyword. Calling `new` on a class [will *always* instantiate a new object based on exactly that class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new), unless the constructor of that class defines something else.

(You might want to get the concept of classes and objects straight, your code example as well as your question seem to indicate that you're not quite clear on that. Maybe reading up on that as well as on the [concept of dependency injection](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) will help you.)

Comment: Thank you. I actually use dependency injection at some places, but not where more than one instance is needed. "you cannot change the behavior of the new keyword." -> this would be enough, but... it's possible to create such "gobal" mocks with Mockery. If Mockery can achieve this due to some black magic, maybe Phpunit can achieve this by itself too.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "global mocks with Mockery"? I don't get it.

Comment: Yes. Replace the original class with the Mock, so that every new Original class creates the Mock instead. With Mockery you could write `$this->myMock = Mockery::mock('overload:' . OriginalCalss::class); $this->myMock->expects('function')->andReturn($stuff);` And when, in the SUT, new OriginalClass->myMock was called, I get $stuff from the Mock instead. So with Mockery it seems to be possible and I was wondering if it would be with Phpunit alone.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a solution to your problem is presented here:
[How to Build a PHP Plugin Module System](https://code-boxx.com/php-plugin-module-system/)

This is one way to load classes as plugins and they can be called from each other. With modifying this system a bit, you can create as many "new OtherClass()" as you like from your code and still access everything from other classes. If you want multiple instances of a class, perhaps modify it into this direction:

```
  function load ($module,$instance) {
    if (isset($this->$module->$instance)) { return true; }
```

From above link:

```
<?php
class Core {
  // (A) PROPERTIES
  public $error = ""; // LAST ERROR MESSAGE
  public $pdo = null; // DATABASE CONNECTION
  public $stmt = null; // SQL STATEMENT
  public $lastID = null; // LAST INSERT/UPDATE ID

  // (B) LOAD SPECIFIED MODULE
  //  $module : module to load
  function load ($module) {
    // (B1) CHECK IF MODULE IS ALREADY LOADED
    if (isset($this->$module)) { return true; }

    // (B2) EXTEND MODULE ON CORE OBJECT
    $file = PATH_LIB . "LIB-$module.php";
    if (file_exists($file)) {
      require $file;
      $this->$module = new $module();
      // EVIL POINTER - ALLOW OBJECTS TO ACCESS EACH OTHER
      $this->$module->core =& $this;
      $this->$module->error =& $this->error;
      $this->$module->pdo =& $this->pdo;
      $this->$module->stmt =& $this->stmt;
      return true;
    } else {
      $this->error = "$file not found!";
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

ps. thank you for the mod, who made me work a bit more to keep this answer online. the answer is so much better now.

Comment: Basically, you are implementing a `service container`... use a framework...

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion, but I don't want to redesin my whole application structure just for the tests. Actually there at least two more simple ways to archive what I want: a) Include a Mock Class File instead of the original (this what I have done until now) in the test or b) use Mockery or such. My Question was exactly if I could the Stub from Phpunit for that or not.

Comment: If things are hard to unit test then that is usually a hint that they should be refactored and restructured. You can choose to ignore that of course. In the long run this will cost you much more for maintaining the application _and_ the tests though.